# Why doesn't pagingTextBox work in IE using dgrid pagination

Tags: dojo, pagination, dgrid

Does anyone happen to know why the pagingTextBox doesn't work when using the dgrid pagination?  It works fine in FireFox and Chrome but when hitting the enter key in the textbox in IE, it does nothing.  I'm using IE 10, but also tried with IE 8.  I need this functionality in all 3 browsers.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only event that the paging textbox listens for is `change`.  Apparently, pressing enter registers this event on Chrome and Firefox but not IE.  I'm not sure what the reasoning is behind that.

This seems like a legitimate issue to report on dgrid's [GitHub issues page](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/issues) though.  It shouldn't take too much effort to fix, even if it means listening for 2 types of events.